# What exactly is that ring, and why didn’t Wong have it before?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, doctor-strange, dr-strange-multiverse-of-madness

In *Doctor Strange in the Multiverse of Madness* (2022), Wanda is seeking the Darkhold after its copy was burned:

> Wong: It's there the Darkhold was transcribed. Mount Wundagore.
>
> Wanda: Wundagore?
>
> Wong: No one has survived the journey.

Using her magic, Wanda retrieved a ring from a nearby corpse and Wong caught it:

[image]

> Wanda: Perhaps we will be the exception.

What exactly is that ring, and why didn’t Wong have it before?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Wanda gives him a [Sling Ring](https://marvelcinematicuniverse.fandom.com/wiki/Sling_Ring). They're used to create portals.

Wong usually carries his on his belt and it was [present in an earlier scene](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Kfvtm.jpg) but he [isn't wearing it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vbbtZ.png) at the point that she gives him the replacement.

We saw Wanda make Doctor Strange's sling ring evaporate when he tried to use it to escape. Presumably the same fate befell Wong's, which is how and why she knew that he needed a new one.

[image]